# Codeigniter project is not working after installing at cpanel

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess, codeigniter-2, cpanel

I build codeigniter project and i have tested it in my local machine using http://works.dev/rcsoft as base url. I upload that project to cpanel and my new url like http://testsomeone.org/rcsoft. Home page is working.

But it is not working for other controller page such as http://testsomeone.org/rcsoft/person. It is giving

```
Not Found

The requested URL /index.php/person was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

But it working for http://testsomeone.org/rcsoft/index.php/person

my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

My config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://testsomeone.org/rcsoft/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Please help me. What is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First open up `application/config/config.php` file and edit line #17 as the example below:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://testsomeone.org/rcsoft/';
```

Second, insert the following line right after `RewriteEngine On` in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteBase /rcsoft/
```

Comment: another $config['index_page'] = '';

Answer (score 0):

Is it working fine in your local machine?..if so then just change the details in routing file..then try ..

Comment: Yes. It is working for my local machine. also localhost/rbsoft. routing file is not change and default controller set to home.